# How can I store :sql_last_value while running in Docker?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am running logstash in docker container. So How can I store :sql_last_value so that even a new container gets created the query should use the last used value not from begining?

below is the conf file.

```
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "<driverpath>/mysql-connector-java-<versionNumber>.jar" 
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://<MySQL host>:3306/es_db" 
    jdbc_user => "<myusername>" 
    jdbc_password => "<mypassword>" 
    jdbc_paging_enabled => true
    tracking_column => "unix_ts_in_secs"
    use_column_value => true
    tracking_column_type => "numeric"
    schedule => "*/5 * * * * *"
    statement => "SELECT *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(modification_time) AS unix_ts_in_secs FROM es_table WHERE (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(modification_time) > :sql_last_value AND modification_time < NOW()) ORDER BY modification_time ASC"
  }
}
filter {
  mutate {
    copy => { "id" => "[@metadata][_id]"}
    remove_field => ["id", "@version", "unix_ts_in_secs"]
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    index => "demo_idx"
    document_id => "%{[@metadata][_id]}"
    ilm_enabled => false
    cloud_id => "<cloud_id>"
    cloud_auth => "<cloud_auth>"
    ssl => true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to store it somewhere in the container using the [`last_run_metadata_path`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html#plugins-inputs-jdbc-last_run_metadata_path) setting and then map that folder to your host in your docker configuration.

```
input {
  jdbc {
     ...
     last_run_metadata_path => "/path/to/last/run"
     ...
  }
}
```

And in your Docker config, you need something to configure a volume like this:

```
...
volumes:
  - /path/to/host:/path/to/last/run
...
```